# mysql connector installed in python 2.6, but not on 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, mysql-python, mysql-connector

RedHat is my OS. By default it runs `python2.6`. However, I needed to install `python2.7`. I installed it following [this post](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2013/02/14/setting-up-django-and-python-2-7-on-red-hat-enterprise-6-the-easy-way/). Now, when I run:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.5
```

however

```
$ sudo python -V
Python 2.6.6
```

So, I incurr problems when installing libraries.
I tried to install `mysql-connector` by:

- `pip install mysql-connector-python`
- following the [installation guide for source distribution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html)
- following the [installation guide for binary distribution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-source-unix.html)

However, mysql-connector module is not installed on the python 2.7 version. If I run:

```
$ python
>>> import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
```

How can I install mysql module also on python version 2.7?

**EDIT**

Additional information:

```
$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip

$ sudo which pip
/usr/bin/pip

$ which easy_install
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/easy_install

$ sudo which easy_install
/usr/bin/easy_install

/usr/bin/ $ ls -al pip
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 281 Feb  7 11:07 pip

/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin $ ls -al easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 344 Aug 16 11:40 easy_install
```

Comment: similiar to **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134782/linux-redhat-6-and-installing-easy-install)**.

Comment: can you import mysql.connector in python 2.6? Maybe the problem isn't with multiple python versions but with the way you try to import?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly why you should use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks, I am seetting up the virtualenv: `virtualenv project --python=python2.7`. However, when trying to run `pip install mysql-connector-python` inside the virtualenv activated, I get the following: Downloading/unpacking mysql-connector-python
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement mysql-connector-python
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external mysql-connector-python to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for mysql-connector-python

Comment: I then managed to install it by `pip install --allow-all-external mysql-connector-python`

Answer (score 1):

Please check where pip and easy_installed are installed? my guess that `which pip` would show pip is in the python 2.6 folder. you need to to reinstall pip and easy_install to the python 2.7 folder. you can do it with :

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python
```

and then check `which easy_install` points to the right direction (you might need to alias/symlink easy_install to the new install. to override the system easy_install) then you can just `easy_install pip`

**Edit (after OP input)**:

1. try to easy_install pip (since the basic easy_install is python 2.7)

**Update:**

Since for some reason python2.7 easy install is installed as root instead of your user you can change ownership of the easy_instlal (or maybe you'll need the entire python2.7 lib. try to change as little as possible) - you can do it with the chown command:

```
chown username:usergroup(usually your username also) path/to/change/ownership
```

Comment: I added the results of the `which`  command. However, when I run the command you posted, I get the following error:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-9203.write-test'

Comment: also run ```ls -al``` on the pip and easy_install location (like ```ls --al /usr/bin/pip```. I suspect the pip is symlinked to somewhere else

Comment: I added the results of `ls -al`.
When running `easy_install pip`, I get the error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-9705.wr‌​ite-test' If I try sudo easy_install pip, it installs it in 2.6 env

Answer (score 0):

You should install pip in python2.7.5 environment. After that pip install will work as expected

Comment: Could you describe hot to install pip for the specific environment?

Comment: It seems easy_install is there in your 2.7 env. Use easy_install pip

Comment: When running `easy_install pip`, I get the error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-9705.write-test'
If I try `sudo easy_install pip`, it installs it in 2.6 env

Comment: try sudo -u username easy_install pip

Comment: Also when using `sudo -u username` It tries to install it in 2.6 env. I even get this error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/test-easy-install-10143.write-test'

Comment: download pip source code. and then go to the directory and run "python setup.py install"

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I just tried, but I have the same error as before: Permission denied
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-10378.write-test

Again: if I use sudo, then it will be installed for 2.6 version :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47005/discussion-between-lima-and-marco)