# how to install and compile prycropto-2.6.1 in remote system

Tags: python, paramiko

How could I install and compile prycropto-2.6.1 in a remote system.I have no clue.Please help .I have tried the below code.

```
easy_install-2.6.1 pip
pip-2.6.1 install pycrypto
```

But the above code is not working. It returns"easy_install-2.6 pip" returns: "No command 'easy_install-2.6' found.what is the process?? I have downloaded the prycrypto-2.6.1 and unzip it .Then what to do next ??

Comment: Maybe you should install easy_install with some package manager related to your specific OS

Comment: if i want to install without the command easy_install what should I do? I am using redhat..

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134782/linux-redhat-6-and-installing-easy-install) hope it will be helpful